# Extend to full width a div inside a contented div

Tags: css, html, css-position

I have a div with a width set (ex. 980px) and a child of that div that I want to extend to full browser width (without expand the parent or overflowing anything).

Worthy to say that the body is positioned as a relative element (and I can't change it).

I thought about using absolute element but got in trouble with other elements near it.

Any help will be very appreciated.

[image: Example]

Comment: How you can expand a child div without expanding it's parent?

Comment: That is why I'm here :)

Answer (score 0):

You don't have to do anything to expand the inner div to 100% of the outer div, *if* you accept things like margins and paddings to be applied as usual. Just take a look at this example I setup for you:

http://jsfiddle.net/3e4yy/4/

HTML:

```
<div class="outer">
    <div class="inner">
        This is the inner div which automatically takes all available width inside the parent container element, which is the outer div in this case.  This is the inner div which automatically takes all available width inside the parent container element, which is the outer div in this case. This is the inner div which automatically takes all available width inside the parent container element, which is the outer div in this case.     
    </div>
</div>

<hr>

<div class="outer">
    <div class="inner">
        This is the inner div which automatically takes all available width inside the parent container element, which is the outer div in this case.  
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
body {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    width: 1100px; 
    height: 500px;
    background-color: lightgray;
}
div {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 10px;
}
.outer {
    width: 980px;
    background-color: blue;
}
.inner {
    background-color: green;
}
```

Comment: Hi @arkascha, thanks for the example but the goal is to make the child 100% of the browser width, not the parent width. I inserted an image on the question.